# WordPress Editor Page Disappeared

Tags: wordpress, editor

I had some guys 'fix' my self-hosted WordPress site after I screwed it up by manipulating the .htcaccess file. It's all working fine now but the editor page has disappeared.

It's a multisite configuration. I used to be able to access 'Editor' from 'Network Admin' under 'Appearance'.

The guys who 'fixed' my site say the editor isn't available with multisite, which I know isn't true.

Any help / advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look in your `wp-config` file, the editor [can be disabled there](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54208/12615). Also check for plugins inside `wp-content/mu-plugins`.

Comment: Yes! In the wp-config file they put ( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );       I deleted it and the editor page has returned. Thank you so much brasofilo!

Comment: Cool, I'll move it into an Answer then. Looks like your *fixing guys* don't trust you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The administrative plugin/theme editor can be disabled through the constant [`DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Disable_the_Plugin_and_Theme_Editor) in the file `wp-config.php`.

It comes as a security measure. As a fellow at WordPress Answers put it: *editing plugin/themes this way is like working on the plane engine while it's on flight*.
The biggest shortcoming is that this editor doesn't have backups. Any simple mistake may take the site down and you'll have to go through FTP to disable the theme/plugin, download it and correct the bug.

I've discussed this constant and its alternatives in this Q&A: [Alternatives to DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT wp-config Constant? It Breaks Some Plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54208/12615).